# Swift 2 didSelectRowAtIndexPath UIAlertController push segue to TVC with 4 strings

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uialertcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm having some trouble passing the value of four labels from my alert Controller to a new cell in another tableViewController. I'm not sure I'm using the best method to pass it on the "add" action.

Here are the relevant snippets ->

***ProductTableViewController.swift***

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell
    // Get the row data for the selected row
    let product = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ProductItem

    cell.productcodeLabel.text = product.productcode
    cell.detailLabel.text = product.detail
    cell.quantityLabel.text = "MOQ \(product.quantity as! Double)"
    cell.barcodeLabel.text = product.barcode

 //MARK: - Add Item Alert
    var quantityTextField = UITextField()

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\(product.detail!)\n \("MOQ \(product.quantity as! Double)")", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("Cancel Button Pressed")
         alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    })

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        // Now do whatever you want with inputTextField (remember to unwrap the optional)
        quantityTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
        print("Add Button Pressed")
        print("You entered \(product.productcode!) \(quantityTextField.text!)")

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let orderVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("addProduct") as! OrderViewController
        orderVC.productcodeString = product.productcode! as String!
        orderVC.detailString = product.detail! as String!
        orderVC.quantityString = quantityTextField.text! as String!
        orderVC.barcodeString = product.barcode! as String!

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(orderVC, animated: true)


    })

        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler{ (quantityTextField) -> Void in
        quantityTextField.placeholder = "Enter quantity here..."
        quantityTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        quantityTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
        quantityTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
        quantityTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
        quantityTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
        quantityTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
        quantityTextField.delegate = self

        }


    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(action)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})

    }
```

***OrderViewController.swift***

```
class OrderViewController: UITableViewController{

var productcodeString = String()
var detailString = String()
var quantityString = String()
var barcodeString = String()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrderTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.productcodeLabel.text = productcodeString
    cell.detailLabel.text = detailString
    cell.quantityLabel.text = "X \(quantityString)"
    cell.barcodeLabel.text = barcodeString

    return cell
   }
```

The segue "addProduct" is drawn from productTVC to orderVC tableviews in the storyboard as a show detail segue.

I get a LLDB in console on the line
let orderVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("addProduct") as! OrderViewController
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

I hope somebody can help me with this drama as im a little lost.

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: When I click the add button in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confused by what you are trying to achieve with your codes. But without trying to analyse it further I can give you some advise on how the flow should be. The method you should be calling here is `prepareForSegue`

when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` fires, you perform the segue `addProduct`

then from `prepareForSegue` you pass the information

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "addProduct") {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! OrderViewController
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let product = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ProductItem
        destination.productcodeString = product.productcode as! String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Product List Alert View "Add Button" segues with strings]

Hi Chris, thanks for the solution you posted. I tried what you offered and not only did it throw an error as well but my scanner segue broke also. I thought a picture may clarify what I am trying to figure out. As you can see when a cell is selected, an alert view with text box pops up to accept a quantity and the Add button is pressed to invoke the segue to OrderViewController with all the data. I can't even get it to segue without data from the alertView.

I'm going to try build an orderDelegate next and focus on just getting the segue to fire without crashing. 
[image: Order List cell receives strings]

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the segue to work properly now!
Here is the final config that actually passes the four strings. Hope it helps someone else...

In the OrderViewController:

```
var passedProductcode = String()
var passedDetail = String()
var passedQuantity = String()
var passedBarcode = String()
```

DidSelectRowAtIndex Method in ProductTableViewController:

```
var selectedPC:String?
var selectedD:String?
var selectedQ:String?
var selectedBC:String?

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true) //Required!
    let product = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ProductItem

    var quantityTextField = UITextField()

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\(product.detail!)" , message: "\("Minimum Order Quantity = \(product.quantity!)")", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("Cancel Button Pressed")
        alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    })

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .Default, handler: { action in
        quantityTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
        //print("Add Button Pressed")
        //print("You entered \(product.productcode!) \(quantityTextField.text!)")

        self.selectedPC = product.productcode!
        self.selectedD = product.detail!
        self.selectedQ = quantityTextField.text!//product.quantity!
        self.selectedBC = product.barcode!
        //print("DSRAIP: \(self.selectedPC!)")
        //print("DSRAIP: \(self.selectedD!)")
        //print("DSRAIP: \(self.selectedQ!)")
        //print("DSRAIP: \(self.selectedBC!)")

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addProduct", sender: self)

    })

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler{ (quantityTextField) -> Void in
        quantityTextField.placeholder = "Enter quantity here..."
        quantityTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        quantityTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
        quantityTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
        quantityTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
        quantityTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
        quantityTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
        quantityTextField.delegate = self
    }

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(action)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})

    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "scanner" {
    let scannerViewController: ScannerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ScannerViewController
    scannerViewController.delegate = self
    print ("Scanner Segue!")
    } else if segue.identifier == "addProduct" {
       print ("Add Item Segue!")
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! OrderViewController
            //print("Segue: \(selectedPC!)")
            //print("Segue: \(selectedD!)")
            //print("Segue: \(selectedQ!)")
            //print("Segue: \(selectedBC!)")
            destination.passedProductcode = (selectedPC)!
            destination.passedDetail = (selectedD)!
            destination.passedQuantity = (selectedQ)!
            destination.passedBarcode = (selectedBC)!
            }
      }
```